# Alternate geom_text position with hjust

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I'm plotting a stacked bar graph and use `geom_text` to insert the value of each stack. The difficulty I'm facing is that some stacks are very small/narrow, so that the text of two stacks overlap each other and hence is not very readable. I would like to adjust the text positioning in a way that for example the text position alternates between `hjust == 1` and `hjust == -1` for each stack, so that there will be no overlaps (or any other method that will result in readable text).

Here's an example of what I'm currently doing (a `dput` of `mydf` is provided below):

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mydf, aes(x=variable, y = value, fill = Category)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = value, y = pos-(value/2)), size = 3)
```

What I tried so far is:

Using `position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)` and `position = position_jitter(h =0.5, w = 0.5)` but none resulted in what I was trying to do.

My first thought was to define `hjust = c(1,-1)` hoping that it would be recycled and texts would alternate between `hjust == 1` and `hjust == -1` but it results in the error message:

```
Error: Incompatible lengths for set aesthetics: size, hjust
```

I also tried defining `size = c(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3), hjust = c(1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1)` but this results in the same error message.

I would appreciate some advice on how to achieve this the right way (and I'm open to other suggestions as well).

I couldn't figure out why the `dput` didn't work (also for me it didn't), so here's the data in readable format:

```
    Category variable value   pos maxpos
1        AX       WW  47.8  47.8  184.1
2        AY       WW   5.6  53.4  184.1
3        AZ       WW  15.8  69.2  184.1
4        BX       WW  31.4 100.6  184.1
5        BY       WW  11.7 112.3  184.1
6        BZ       WW  10.7 123.0  184.1
7        CX       WW   2.2 125.2  184.1
8        CY       WW  21.4 146.6  184.1
9        CZ       WW  37.5 184.1  184.1
10       AX       SM  39.8  39.8  148.6
11       AY       SM   2.9  42.7  148.6
12       AZ       SM  13.2  55.9  148.6
13       BX       SM  22.7  78.6  148.6
14       BY       SM   7.3  85.9  148.6
15       BZ       SM   8.9  94.8  148.6
16       CX       SM   1.6  96.4  148.6
17       CY       SM  17.3 113.7  148.6
18       CZ       SM  34.9 148.6  148.6
19       AX     AsIs 156.9 156.9  519.0
20       AY     AsIs  13.1 170.0  519.0
21       AZ     AsIs  70.5 240.5  519.0
22       BX     AsIs  72.6 313.1  519.0
23       BY     AsIs  30.7 343.8  519.0
24       BZ     AsIs  35.6 379.4  519.0
25       CX     AsIs   5.2 384.6  519.0
26       CY     AsIs  44.8 429.4  519.0
27       CZ     AsIs  89.6 519.0  519.0
```

Comment: I fail to load your `dput` for some reason

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I don't know what was wrong, hope you don't mind using the other format.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50060510/2270475 for another neat solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By creating a `hjust` variable, you can achieve the desired result. The code:

```
mydf$hj <- rep(c(1,0,-1), length.out=27)

ggplot(mydf, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=Category)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label=value, y=pos-(value/2), hjust=hj), size=4)
```

which gives:
[image]

---

A slightly alternative solution proposed by [@konvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626769/alternate-geom-text-position-hjust#comment38168437_24627761):

```
ggplot(mydf, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=Category)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label=value, y=pos-(value/2), hjust=rep(c(1,0,-1), length.out=length(value))), size=4)
```

Comment: Thanks Jaap, that's just what I needed :) +1

Comment: Or avoid creating the new variable explicitly, and add `hjust = rep(c(-1, 1), length.out = length(value))` in your original call (inside `aes`).

Comment: @Jaap I know this is 7 years old, but I have an exact similar issue and I'm having trouble adjusting `hj` values to fix the issue. Would you mind assisting, please?

Comment: @Jaap specifically I don't understand the role of `y` value inside aes(), and why you chose a vector of length 3 for `hj`? I would appreciate your response.